# How do I reference a constructor in an XML comment in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, xml-comments

Let's say I have the following code:

```
Public Sub New(num As Integer)

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' <see cref=""/>
''' </summary>
Public Sub DoSomething()

End Sub
```

What do I put between the quotation marks in `cref=""` to reference `New(Integer)`?

Comment: You're missing the end tag `''' <see cref="New(Integer)"/>`

Comment: @Jimi Oops, added the slash, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`New(Integer)` will suffice:

```
''' <summary>
''' <see cref="New(Integer)">
''' </summary>
Public Sub DoSomething()

End Sub
```

If you hover over it, you will see that Visual Studio interprets it correctly:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Oh so I had it right in the first place; IntelliSense is just being weird. Thanks!

Comment: @NetherGranite: For some reason, auto-complete works if you start typing `ClassName.New` but not if you just type `New`. But just `New` is fine as well.

Comment: Yeah VS is rendering the XML comment properly, but, IntelliSense still tells me it `Cannot resolve symbol 'New'`, even if I try `ClassName.New` for some reason. Maybe a restart of VS will fix it.

Comment: @Slai Wouldn't that be equivalent to `MyClass<Integer>()` in C#? The signature I was going for was `MyClass(Integer)`.

Comment: @NetherGranite yes, exactly. I am just not familiar with the `MyClass(Integer)` without `Of` syntax.